# How can I insert a comma into pre-existing strings in R?

Tags: r, regex, string

I have data that looks similar to the following example:

| DATA |
| --- |
| PRETEND COUNTY JP |
| FAKE COUNTY,TX JP 1.1 |
| Madeup City,TX |
| Not Real County, JP 2.5 |

How can add the " ,TX " to the counties that don't have it such as the first cell?

I'd like to have a dataset that would then look like:

| DATA |
| --- |
| PRETEND COUNTY, TX JP |
| FAKE COUNTY, TX JP 1.1 |
| Madeup City, TX |
| Not Real County, TX JP 2.5 |

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(address = str_replace(address, "(?i)(?<=(COUNTY|CITY)),?\\s(?=JP)", ", TX "))
                     address
1      PRETEND COUNTY, TX JP
2      FAKE COUNTY,TX JP 1.1
3             Madeup City,TX
4 Not Real County, TX JP 2.5
```

How this works:

1. `(?i)`: case-insensitive flag
2. `(?<=(COUNTY|CITY))`: positive look-behind: match only if you see either `"county" or "city" to the left of the match
3. `,?\\s`: match an optional comma and a whitespace
4. `(?=JP)`: but only iff on the right of match there is "JP"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the exact requirements, but you can try using regular expressions.

```r
# build example data
df <-
  data.frame(
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                DATA = c("PRETEND COUNTY JP",
                         "FAKE COUNTY,TX JP 1.1","Madeup City,TX",
                         "Not Real County, JP 2.5")
  )

# build regular expression
pattern <- stringr::regex('county', ignore_case = TRUE)

# use regular expression to make new desired column
df2 <-
  df |> 
    dplyr::mutate(
      DATA2 = 
        dplyr::case_when(
          stringr::str_detect(DATA, "TX") ~ DATA,
          TRUE ~ stringr::str_replace(DATA, pattern ,"County, TX")
        )
    )

df2
#>                      DATA                       DATA2
#> 1       PRETEND COUNTY JP       PRETEND County, TX JP
#> 2   FAKE COUNTY,TX JP 1.1       FAKE COUNTY,TX JP 1.1
#> 3          Madeup City,TX              Madeup City,TX
#> 4 Not Real County, JP 2.5 Not Real County, TX, JP 2.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>